# Specify Video Start Time in Player API

Tags: actionscript-3, time, youtube

I'm embedding a player in an HTML page and want a video to start playing at a specific time point... in other words, skip stuff at the start of the video.

Using the Demo at https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo it states that you can specify a time at which the video should start playing. If I specify a time (using AS3) and click on "Update player with selected options" then it loads my video at jumps to the specified time.

However, at the bottom of the page where it shows you the "Embed code" there is nothing to indicate the start time.

I did find a reference through a Google search that says **#t=1m45s** can be specified. However, I cannot find a clear example of how it's implemented. When I try to use the following in my HTML page, it has no effect. The video starts at the beginning.

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/kBySbbvap6E#?version=3#t=1m45s&playlist=HCKBnXOG5uM,tS2O-YHfj6I,Vogl7GIggXI&autoplay=1&autohide=1&fs=1&feature=player_embedded">
```

All other options that I've specified work as expected. I did try to position the time spec at several different places on the line, none had any effect.

Also, I've loaded the page in Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE... same results in all browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just noticed that there is a '#' infront of your time parameter. It should be changed to '&' for proper URL encoding. That might just fix your whole issue :).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are specifically asking about the YouTube api, rather than the flash API. It is relatively easy to start a Youtube video at the specified time. Take the following trailer for Pacific Rim. I'll start it at 50 seconds

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vKz7WnU83E&t=0m50s
```

The trick is the 't' parameter

```
&t=0m50s
```

It is formatted as [X]h[X]m[X]s where [X] is your integer time value for that unit of time.

On your url, i see that

```
t=1m45s.
```

Is it possible that this time is greater than the length of the video?? It seems if i pass a value greater than the length, the video just doesn't play and goes to the ending 'suggestions' screen.